# SyntaxError in console.log('Test');

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up VS Code and Node.js so I can actually start learning JavaScript. When I run this code `console.log('Test');` in VS Code I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I have read somewhere that maybe I have some hidden characters so I installed ESLint, Gremlins, and Tabnine extensions with the hope to see some issues in that super simple code, but I could not.

Additionally, this code works perfectly well in the Browser>Terminal or in the Windows terminal. What I am missing here?

Comment: How can I reproduce this?  Can you copy and paste the code into your question?  (And then, of course, you yourself copy and paste the code from the question into a new file and try again to see if you can reproduce it.)

Comment: The issue was resolved by downloading "Tabnine" and switching to UTF-8